# How to read the event when a Cloud Function is triggered in a Firebase Extension?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-extensions

I'm trying to follow the docs regarding [get started with a Firebase Extension](https://firebase.google.com/docs/extensions/publishers/get-started) using [Firebase Functions Firestore 2nd-gen](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions-2nd-gen). Inside my extension.yaml file I have created a resource:

```
resources:
  - name: onDocCreate
    type: firebaseextensions.v1beta.function
    description: >-
      A function that fires when a new document is created.
    properties:
      eventTrigger: 
        eventType: providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.create
        resource: projects/${PROJECT_ID}/databases/(default)/documents/docs/{docId}
      runtime: "nodejs18"
```

Inside my index.js file, I have added these lines of code:

```
const {
  onDocumentCreated,
} = require("firebase-functions/v2/firestore");

exports.onDocCreate = onDocumentCreated("docs/{docId}", (event) => {
  const data = event.data;
  if (!data) {
    console.log("No data associated with the event");
    return;
  }
  const docId = event.params.docId;
  console.log("docId: " + docId);
});
```

When I a dd a new document in the "docs" collection I always get:

> No data associated with the event

As per my understanding, the `onDocumentCreated` fires but with no data. If I comment the first 5 lines and I try to log the `docId`, I always get:

> docId: undefined

How solve this issue?

---

```
resources:
  - name: onDocCreate
    type: firebaseextensions.v1beta.function
    description: >-
      A function that fires when a new document is created.
    properties:
      eventTrigger: 
        eventType: google.cloud.firestore.document.v1.created
        resource: projects/${PROJECT_ID}/databases/(default)/documents/docs/{docId}
      runtime: "nodejs18"
      platform: "gcfv2"
```

Comment: The `eventType` you are using in your YAML defines a `firestore.onCreate` Cloud Function 1st gen. I don't think Firebase Extensions support Cloud Functions 2nd gen yet. If they did, I think your YAML would need to use the [2nd gen event type](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/blob/3e7a4b77967e46a067712445c499c5df005b8e31/src/v2/providers/firestore.ts#L44-L45) of `google.cloud.firestore.document.v1.created` along with `platform: "gcfv2"` in your `properties` map (i.e. not under `eventTrigger`).

Comment: @samthecodingman Thanks for taking the time to comment at my question. I just tried what you have suggested, as in my updated question, but I get this error: `BadRequest","fieldViolations":[{"field":"function","description":"Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"platform\" at 'function': Cannot find field."}]}]...`.

Comment: Seems I was right and that v2 aren't supported yet. For now, rework your function to target v1 Cloud Functions.

Comment: @samthecodingman Thank you, Sam. If you want to post that as answer, it will be great.

Comment: Actually, in the process of hydrating the comment to a full answer I found the changes you need to make.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*firebaser here*

Firestore triggers for v2 functions are currently not documented, but should work.

As suggested in some other responses, the resource type for v2 functions must be `firebaseextensions.v1beta.v2function`. You can use some other documented v2 triggert as an example here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/extensions/publishers/functions#crashlytics

Also, the resource filter format is different for v2 functions. It relies on Eventarc event filtering, so you need to use event filter syntax. Some available Firestore filters are documented here: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore#deploy_the_hello_firestore_function

Also, event filter syntax for v2 functions is documented here: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.functions.v2#eventfilter

So, perhaps try something like this:

```yaml
resources:
  - name: ondoccreate
    type: firebaseextensions.v1beta.v2function
    description: >-
      A function that fires when a new document is created.
    properties:
      buildConfig:
        runtime: nodejs18
      eventTrigger:
        eventType: google.cloud.firestore.document.v1.created
        triggerRegion: nam5
        eventFilters:
          - attribute: database
            value: (default)
          - attribute: document
            value: docs/{docId}
            operator: match-path-pattern
```

(also note the function naming requirements for v2 functions, upper case letters are not supported)

EDIT: added the required `triggerRegion`. You might want to make it a parameter for users to control, at least until the extensions platform adds a way automatically infer it.

Comment: Hey pavelgj. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. Let me try your solution and I get back top you.

Comment: If you have time, while I'm testing your solution, maybe you can take a look at my new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77045379/how-to-solve-lacks-iam-permission-when-backfill-data-in-firebase-extension)? Thanks

Comment: I just tried your solution but I get `The request was invalid: unsupported Cloud Firestore region us-central1: invalid argument","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","statusMessage":"Bad`. Why?

Comment: Hm, this looks similar to https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/1408

Can you try adding `triggerRegion: global` to `eventTrigger` configuration? Similar to https://firebase.google.com/docs/extensions/publishers/functions#crashlytics

Comment: Yes. Let me try it.

Comment: I added `triggerRegion: global` as suggested, but I get `The request was invalid: invalid value for attribute 'type' in trigger.event_filters: type \"google.cloud.firestore.document.v1.created\" is not allowed in global location","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","statusMessage":"Bad`.

Comment: Not super familiar with Firestore regions, a bit of a trial-and-error here, sorry... https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/locations#types
Can you try `triggerRegion: nam5`? Or `triggerRegion: us-central`? This may need to be a separate param that you let your extension users configure... or a feature requires for the extensions platform to figure out and inject `triggerRegion` automatically.

Comment: I tried with `us-central1`, which is the default region for the project and didn't work either. The exact same error as earlier, `The request was invalid: unsupported Cloud Firestore region us-central1:` :( Btw, thank you a lot for trying to help. The docs are awful.

Comment: Yes, is `us-central1` is not a supported region, it's either `us-central` (note the absence of `1` at the end) or `nam5`.

Comment: Let me try that. As far as I know, those are for multi region, but it doesn't matter, I just want to make it work. I try it now.

Comment: It really worked man, thank you so much!!! I used `us-central` and I got the following message: `Available regions are: asia, asia-east1, asia-east2, asia-northeast1, asia-northeast2, asia-northeast3, asia-south1, asia-south2, asia-southeast1, asia-southeast2, asia1, australia-southeast1, australia-southeast2, eu, eur3, eur4, europe-central2, europe-north1, europe-southwest1, europe-west1, europe-west12, europe-west2, europe-west3, europe-west4, europe-west6, europe-west8, europe-west9, global, me-central1, me-west1, nam4, nam5, northamerica-northeast1`.

Comment: + `northamerica-northeast2, southamerica-east1, southamerica-west1, us, **us-central1**, us-east1, us-east4, us-east5, us-east7, us-south1, us-west1, us-west2, us-west3, us-west4.`. Even if `us-central1` is indicated as a supported region, it's not. However it worked with `nam5`.

Comment: I tried again to be 100% sure and it works. Thank you!!

Comment: Great! I updated the answer with `triggerRegion`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get a "No data associated with the event" message is because the extension is defined with a 1st gen compatible trigger, but the code is only listening for a 2nd gen compatible trigger. Because of the differences in the request bodies, the data is not properly parsed for use in your function.

---

This line in your `extension.yaml` file targets a `firestore.onCreate` Cloud Function 1st gen:

```yaml
eventType: providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.create
```

To target an `onDocumentCreated` Cloud Function for 2nd gen, you would have to update it to use the correct [`eventType`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/blob/3e7a4b77967e46a067712445c499c5df005b8e31/src/v2/providers/firestore.ts#L44-L45):

```yaml
eventType: google.cloud.firestore.document.v1.created
```

Now that you have the correct `eventType` there are a couple of other properties to be updated according to the [`extension.yaml` reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/extensions/reference/extension-yaml#2nd-gen) -  the value for `type` and `properties.buildConfig.runtime` (instead of using `properties.runtime`):

```yaml
resources:
  - name: onDocCreate
    type: firebaseextensions.v1beta.v2function
    description: >-
      A function that fires when a new document is created.
    properties:
      buildConfig:
        runtime: nodejs18
      eventTrigger:
        eventType: google.cloud.firestore.document.v1.created
        resource: projects/${PROJECT_ID}/databases/(default)/documents/docs/{docId}
```

You should then be able to deploy this resource with your extension.

Comment: Thank you, Sam for your answer. I feed like we're very close. The earlier error is gone, but I got a new one, `field resource not found in type functions.eventTriggerV2.; `spec.resources`: generic::invalid_argument`. It seems to me that the `resource` field has a problem. Any idea? The `resource` filed in my case is needed because I need to specify the path.

Comment: I tried changing the `resource` with `channel`, but it doesn't work either. I get `failed to get channel for project xxx region  channel ID : unsupported region`. Where the region is `Iowa (us-central1)`.