# How to solve lacks IAM permission when backfill data in Firebase extension?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-tasks, firebase-extensions

I'm trying to create a simple Firebase extension. I have a few Cloud functions that work fine and I also enabled the option to backfill existing users. This means that when someone installs the extension, I will add a ranking (number) in the Realtime Database.

This is what I have tried. In my extension.yaml file, I have added:

```
  - name: backfillDocs
    type: firebaseextensions.v1beta.function
    description: >-
      Rank users
    properties:
      runtime: "nodejs16"
      taskQueueTrigger: {}
```

And I want to do that on install:

```
lifecycleEvents:
  onInstall:
    function: backfillDocs
    processingMessage: Setting the rank.
```

I checked the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/extensions/publishers/lifecycle-events#long-running), and here is what I have tried with my function:

```
exports.backfillDocs = tasks
    .taskQueue()
    .onDispatch(async (data) => {
      const offset = data["offset"] !== undefined ? data["offset"] : 0;

      const snapshot = await getFirestore()
          .collection("users")
          .limit(DOCS_PER_BACKFILL)
          .get();

      const processed = await Promise.allSettled(
          snapshot.docs.map(async (doc) => {
            const ref = getDatabase().ref().child("rankings").child(doc.id);
            await ref.set(0);
          }),
      );

      if (processed.length == DOCS_PER_BACKFILL) {
        const queue = getFunctions().taskQueue(
            "backfilldata",
            process.env.EXT_INSTANCE_ID,
        );
        return await queue.enqueue({
          offset: offset + DOCS_PER_BACKFILL,
        });
      } else {
        return getExtensions().runtime()
            .setProcessingState(
                "PROCESSING_COMPLETE",
                "Backfill complete.",
            );
      }
    });
```

The problem is that, each time I install the extension, I get:

```
Error: The principal (user or service account) lacks IAM permission "cloudtasks.tasks.create"
```

I don't see why I get this error since I have enabled `Cloud Tasks Enqueuer` to `project-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`, `firebase-adminsdk-*****@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com` and `firebase-service-account@firebase-sa-management.iam.gserviceaccount.com`. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

What am I missing? Please help.

Comment: Could you please check which roles the following service account has in your project? `service-PROJECT_NUMBER@gcp-sa-firebasemods.iam.gserviceaccount.com`
It should be `Firebase Extensions API Service Agent`

Comment: @pavelgj As you can see in the screenshot, I don't even have such an account. Should I create one?

Comment: I have a feeling the screenshot is not showing the whole picture. Could you please make sure the "Include Google-provided role grants" checkbox is selected?
https://cloud.google.com/static/iam/img/include-google-provided-role-grants.png

Comment: Yes, you're right, it was unchecked. I checked it now and yes, `service-PROJECT_NUMBER@gcp-sa-firebasemods.iam.gserviceaccount.com` is set to `Firebase Extensions API Service Agent` :| What could then be the problem? Thanks for the effort. I really apreciate it.

Comment: Where do you see the error (can you share a screenshot perhaps)? Basically, I'd like to understand whether this error comes from extensions backend (when it's attempting to create the first lifecycle event task) or whether it's an error coming from the `backfillDocs` function. 

Here's a working reference implementation, and it looks like you're doing everything pretty much the same way:
https://github.com/firebase/extensions/blob/78c62f9504ea4773c68a9b778cf8243f60cdf536/storage-resize-images/extension.yaml#L64

Comment: Yes, I already seen that, but it's version 1, not 2nd version. I see the error in the Google Cloud Console, when the function is triggered, I just open the logs. Here is the entire error message: `Exception from a finished function: Error: The principal (user or service account) lacks IAM permission "cloudtasks.tasks.create" for the resource "projects/project-id/locations/us-central1/queues/ext-extension-name-backfillDocs" (or the resource may not exist).`.

Comment: AFAIK, v2 functions are currently not supported as `taskQueueTrigger` (or lifecycle events) in extensions. Only triggers that are documented are known to work well. As you can see from your other question (https://stackoverflow.com/q/77036317/1895949) the undocumented triggers either don't work, or don't yet have great developer experience. I would suggest you stick with v1 functions for lifecycle events. If you really need v2, please file a feature request: https://github.com/firebase/extensions/issues/new/choose

Comment: I'm sorry, 2nd gen were for the other question. For this one, I'll keep v1. So the error from my question persists :( If you'll have any new idea, please share them with me.

Comment: OK, then two things to check:
1. Make sure that the task queue exists by going to https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudtasks and make sure `ext-extension-name-backfillDocs` is listed there in region `us-central1`.
2. Make sure the extension service account has the "Cloud Tasks Enqueuer" role granted on the queue. Click on the "checkbox" next to the queue name while in the queue list view (https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudtasks) and permissions panel will open on the right. Make sure `ext-EXTENSION_ID@PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com`  is listed there.

Comment: @pavelgj Hey. I just want to confirm that [both conditions are met](https://i.ibb.co/1L8v0RH/Screenshot-2023-09-06-130956.png). I changed the name of the function from `backfillDocs` to `doBackfillExistingDocuments` but the flow is the same. Any other idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The queue name in the code must match the function name. It appears your function is called  `doBackfillExistingDocuments` so when getting the queue ref you need to use the same name:

```js
exports.doBackfillExistingDocuments = tasks
    .taskQueue()
    .onDispatch(async (data) => {
        // ...
        const queue = getFunctions().taskQueue(
            "doBackfillExistingDocuments", // <----
            process.env.EXT_INSTANCE_ID,
        );
        // ...
     });
```

Comment: That's brilliant man. It really worked, no more "lacks IAM permission". I can't believe that. I was struggling with this issue for days. Thank you so much for bearing with me.

Comment: I've struggled for days searching how to solve the IAM permission "cloudtasks.tasks.create" problem and I couldn't find a solution. Now, my code works perfect thanks to you. This is a sign of appreciation and again a big thank you.

Comment: If you have time, maybe you can also help me with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77090651/how-to-not-backfill-documents-in-firebase-extension).